# Is it possible to get the ActiveRecord::Relation object for an association

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, arel

1. Do association methods, such as those defined by `has_many` and `belongs_to` utilize `ActiveRecord::Relation`?
2. If so, is it possible to get the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that is being used.

We're all aware that Rails 3 is heavily using `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, and `Arel::Relation` objects in the background, when creating queries using the [Query Interface](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database). Whenever we use the `select`, `joins`, etc. methods of the Query Interface, a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object is returned. However, this doesn't seem to be the case when calling an association method of a model. Instead, the query is executed immediately and an instance, or an array of instances, of the associated model is returned.

Consider the following models:

`post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`user.rb`

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Example:

```
u = User.first
u.posts
```

Calling `u.posts` returns an array of posts, not an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I'm wondering if it's possible to get the `ActiveRecord::Relation` that is *being used by the association*, if it is being used at all, perhaps by using `Arel::Table`?

My reasoning for wanting the `ActiveRecord::Relation` should be obvious: It is because I want to chain off the existing association and manipulate the query to suit a different purpose.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a few minutes I used the `where(nil)` hack, then I had a brainwave and tried something random:

```
User.first.posts.scoped
```

That's it! :D

Yeah, Rails + Arel is really poorly documented. Looking forward to it maturing to the point where I can actually look things up and get actual answers.

Comment: Love it. Much cleaner! I'm giving you the CHECKMARK. And I agree about the Arel documentation. I've been reading scraps and bits all over the place about it. It seems very powerful, but without good documentation, it can be quite annoying as well. :)

Comment: is there a way to call `.scoped` on a custom array that I made?

Comment: (The answer to that is no: `scoped` only makes sense on a top-level class :/)

Comment: Interestingly .scoped even works for has_and_belongs_to_many, which otherwise returns an Array.

Comment: `.scoped` is depreciated

Answer (score 4):

in Rails 4, use `.scope` or `.spawn` to access the relation object instead of the `CollectionProxy`. See the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-scope).

Answer (score 1):

By taking the time to actually read the Edge Guides documentation, I was able to find *an* answer in [Section 4.3 `has_many` Association Reference](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference). In short, the documentation does not shed light on whether it possible to get the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object or whether an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object is being used, but it does provide detail on how to reuse the association and tailor its result.

Section [4.3.1 Methods Added by `has_many`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has_many) lists the *`collection`*`.where` as being one of the methods that is added by the `has_many` association. And section [4.3.1.11 *`collection`*`.where(…)`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection-where) shows that you would use it just as you would user the `where` method of the query interface. More importantly, it gives a hint that *objects are lazily loaded* when using this method on the collection, and sure enough, an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object is returned.

```
u.posts.where("").class  # => ActiveRecord::Relation
u.posts.where("").to_sql # => SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.user_id = 1
```

Admittedly, not the ideal solution, but it does give me something I can chain off of.

Answer (score 1):

In an `ActiveSupport::Concern`, you can't call the private method `spawn` or use `scope` or `scoped`.

I needed to use this.

```
where(true)
```